# how to print db_select result using watchdog?

Tags: database, debugging, log-messages

I'm trying to debug below code:

```
$perishables = db_select('userpoints_txn', 'up_txn')
    ->fields('up_txn', array('txn_id', 'uid', 'points', 'remainder', 'time_stamp', 'tid', 'operation', 'description'))
    ->condition('status', 0, '=')
    ->condition('expired', 0, '=')
    ->condition('expirydate', 0, '!=')
    ->condition('expirydate', REQUEST_TIME, '<')
    ->execute();
 watchdog('userpoints', 'perishables->remainder  %perrr', array('%perrr' =>$perishables), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
```

Can anyone help me how to get  $perishables in the report log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print_r()` with the `$return` argument set as `TRUE`.

*example*

```
watchdog('userpoints', 'perishables->remainder %perrr', array('%perrr' => print_r($perishables, TRUE)), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.I replaced my watchdog statement,but still  i'm not able to find result  in recent log reports

Comment: My answer was based on the question, you only get results when you fetch them, as mentioned in @arpitr's answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. execute(): - this will not return query results to you. All it will return is database connection object and query string. See the screen shot.
   [image]
2. In order to get query results, you need to call any of the [retrieve function](https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174). For example

   fetch();        // Use the default fetch mode.

   fetchObject();  // Fetch as a stdClass object.

   fetchAssoc();   // Fetch as an associative array.
3. Debugging queries:

   I would recommend you to use devel module and its help functions as [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) and [dpq()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) . They will make your debugging process a lot more faster can clean than watchdog.
4. watchdog() - I confirm the answer by @Decipher(+1) will record the query object in database, see the scrrenshot tested with a simple query
   [image]

Might be that log is not something that you want to see, a small change to @Decipher answer if you want to see the query String

```
watchdog('userpoints', 'perishables->remainder %perrr', array('%perrr' => print_r($perishables->queryString, TRUE)), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
```

**You can definitely make it better the way you want with above mentioned tools**

Comment: Agreed, it's better to use the devel module and dpm() & dpq(), you can run the query and see the results straight away without digging in the logs.